# Model View Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

It sounds like to me that the Model class holds information about all or nearly all attributes in a program... so should it contain things like getters and setters? Or am I getting the wrong idea?

Comment: In the sense of encapsulation, your model would contain the getters and setters for your Model objects as appropriate.  In the big picture view, a Model should contain all the structure of the data, a View should know how to display the Model, and a Controller should know how to process the results of user input in a View.

Answer (score 2):

getters and setters are nothing to do with Models, But act as a great tool, So i think your righti n a sence, but you should understand that Getters and Setters having nothing to do with the model principle but are a way to construct your Model Classes to suite your Framework.

With MVC, The Model is mainly Data, getting and setting is vital part of data management, where as Controller is the `Decision Maker` in all this, Can the user have this information, can the user set the information..

How MVC Usually works in my mind is like so:

- Controller takes care of the decisions, What views to load, etc
- Model is the layer between the view and the database / storage, and acts as Getter + Setters
- The View is the GUI, which is in the middle of the user and the Model

So the View asks the controller if it can show certain data, and then the view will respond true / false depending in the login, if true, the View will then ask the Model for the information

Thats the way interoperate MVC, I may be slightly off but more or less this is usually how it goes

hopefully this image will give you a better description then above:
[image]

But in regards to your primary question, I would always associate Getters + Settings with Model Abstraction.